# How can I tell a page "those files are no-longer here, they're here..." via .htaccess?

Tags: apache

I have a site on a server with access to ftp but no SSH.

Because of necessary DNS changes, the homepage of the site is trying to load images from a file path that doesn't exist.

Can I use .htaccess to tell the page where the files are located?

All of the files it is looking for are in a folder, but the nesting structure is different than it was before the DNS change.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^oldpage.html$ http://yoursite.com/newpage.html [R=301,L]
```

Comment: thank you, would I want to do ^/oldpage\.html$ to break the period though?

Answer (score 2):

Try [`Alias`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html)?

```
Alias /the/url/path/that/no/longer/exists /physical/path/to/where/files/are
```

Comment: I don't know how I can do this without SSH access. It's one of those cheap shared servers

Comment: You can put the alias directives into .htaccess files as well.

Comment: I want to give answer to both =( +1s instead

Comment: For some reason, this isn't working in windows 7 x64 / wamp. (I have mod_rewrite enabled)... getting an internal server error. Chris' solution is working - but I like the idea of just using an Alias